# What does `{}` do in general?

Tags: environments, newtheoremstyle

I came across this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251053/how-to-use-case-1-case-2-in-a-proof-ieee-confs), the answer achieves what it does, but there is no explanation of how it works. I have some ideas that `{}` serves as a placeholder for `\newtheoremstyle`. I tried to experiment a bit and added one more `{}` to the command `\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}`, but this failed.

In another comment of the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251053/how-to-use-case-1-case-2-in-a-proof-ieee-confs), `{}` was also used in `\newenvironment`, for example, `\newenvironment{}{}{}`.

I could not find any reference as to what `{}` actually does in the context of Latex in general. Where can I find some references of the command `{}`?

Comment: The `{}` are empty mandatory arguments to the command `\newtheoremstyle`. See [the `amsthm` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) for the meaning of all the arguments. And because the number of mandatory arguments of `\newtheoremstyle` is fixated it also does not make sense to add one more `{}`. Moreover, this question looks like a [XY Problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449). So: Please, ask the real problem and illustrate it by a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as hinted in a different comment, this is specific to the package used, and described in the manual. In other words: the degree of freedom, the TO tries, does not exist here.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks for the reference. What does `{}` do in the command `\newenvironment{}{}{}`?

Comment: `\newenvironment{}{}{}` would define a new environment without name, without begin code, and without end code. And because this would redefine `\end`, it would break LaTeX. So it would not only not make any sense, but also would not be a good idea. Please read a LaTeX introduction or the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172511/277964) already referred in the comment to the question you've linked to for more information about `\newenvironment` and other basics.

Comment: Generally speaking, unless a syntax is explicitly documented, the answer to "what do X do" is "it's an artifact because of some internal implementation detail" -- as such unless you have some TeX programming experience it's best to not care about these things. ■ But otherwise refer to [tikz pgf - How to find the documentation for a package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380019/how-to-find-the-documentation-for-a-package/380075#380075)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and/86396#86396